# Grab a property of an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object `comments`. It **can** be undefined in some cases and in the other cases it looks like

```
{
  id: 1,
  ...,
  next_page: 'someurl' // can also be undefined in some cases
}
```

I need to grab that `next_page` property if it exist or make it null in other cases. My code:

```
let next_page = null;

if (comments && comments.next_page)
  next_page = comments.next_page
```

It works, but i'm feeling like there is some easier way. Am i right?

Comment: `let next_page = comments && comments.next_page || null`?

Comment: @CRice no, because if next_page is 0, that condition returns null.

Comment: @CRice I knew it :) Post your answer

Comment: @Ele As you see from example, `next_page` is URL, so it's ok in my case

Comment: @Src yes, but is not ok.  be careful.

Comment: CRice, for your solution if comments.next_page isnt defined then next_page gets set to comments instead of null.

Comment: When you say it's `undefined`, do you mean it's just missing from the object? Or is the key there but the value is `undefined`?

Comment: @Perspective missing

Comment: @webnetweaver Not to my knowledge? If `comments` or `comments.next_page` are falsy, then the entire left side of the `||` will be falsy and it should use the value from the right side of the `||` operator, which is `null`.

Comment: @CRice sure. He's probably misunderstood that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be null? If so, go with:

```
const next_page = comments && comment.next_page || null
```

If `undefined` is fine as well, I'd suggest:

```
const next_page = comments && comment.next_page
```

Javascript is behaving a bit unexpectedly here. The result of the expression right of the equals sign is `undefined` if `next_page` does not exist on `comment`, but `comment.next_page` if it does exist.

*Edit:
As pointed out in a different comment: be careful when `next_page` is a falsy value as version #1 will return `null`, when `comment.next_page` is `0`.*

Comment: Thank's for the answer! Can't accept it though, because @CRice wrote this way first

Comment: @Src I don't want to polute the answers with one thats basically identical. This one looks legit and you should 100% accept it.

Comment: @CRice As you wish :)

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the `if()` block returns the value of the expression (not boolean), so you can condense it into one line:

```
let next_page = ( comments && comments.next_page );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the property is missing maybe you can have a template object and won't have to assign it.

```
const template = { id: null, nextPage: nul};
const useThis = Object.assign({}, template, dataMaybeHasNextPage)

// if dataMaybeHasNextPage object has nextPage then useThis.nextPage would a url
```

That way nextPage would always be set.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```js
const defaultCommentObj = { id: null, nextPage: null};
const commentA = Object.assign({}, defaultCommentObj, {
  id: 1,
  nextPage: 'https://google.com',
});

const commentB = Object.assign({}, defaultCommentObj, {
  id: 2,
});

console.log('A : ', commentA);
console.log('B : ', commentB);
```